# How to get list of stripped by Proguard methods and classes?

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

Proguard removes unused methods and classes during optimization. How to get list of them?

Comment: There is something about retracing https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/retrace

Comment: @meditat seems like this tool can recreate names in stacktrace. it isn't my task. my task is analyze what part of my code was removed from the application.

Comment: it is giving you the `obfuscated code` and the `mapping file` which you can use to reproduce your code or methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should use `printusage`

As per proguard

> `-printusage [filename]`
>   Specifies to list dead code of the input class files. The list is printed to the standard output or to the given file. For example, you can list the unused code of an application. Only applicable when shrinking.

This is code which will be removed at the time of optimization, though you can also control optimization process.